# Configuration file dataConfiguration.config does not have root <configuration> tag

Tags: c#, configuration, enterprise-library

I am having some issues using Enterprise Library to share configuration information across several files. I have three configuration files (app.config, dataConfiguration.config, and exceptionHandlingConfiguration.config). I am working with Enterprise library 5.0 and Visual Studio 2012, on a Windows 7 machine in .NET 4.0 framework.

In App.config, I have the following

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>
    <appSettings> 
    </appSettings>
    <enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="SysConfig">
        <sources>
            <add name="SysConfig" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.SystemConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                 />
            <add name="DataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                filePath="dataConfiguration.config" />
            <add name="ExceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                filePath="exceptionHandlingConfiguration.config" />
        </sources>
        <redirectSections>
            <add sourceName="DataConfiguration" name="dataConfiguration" />
            <add sourceName="ExceptionHandling" name="exceptionHandling" />
        </redirectSections>
    </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
</configuration>
```

exceptionHandlingConfiguration.config contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
              postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow" />
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
  <validation />
  <policyInjection>
    <policies>
      <add name="Application Policy">
        <handlers>
           <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.PolicyInjection.ValidationCallHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              specificationSource="Both" name="Validation Call Handler" /> 

        </handlers>
      </add>
      <add name="Global Policy">
        <handlers>
          <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.PolicyInjection.ExceptionCallHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              exceptionPolicyName="Policy" name="Exception Handling Call Handler" /> 

        </handlers>
      </add>
    </policies>
  </policyInjection>
</configuration>
```

While dataConfiguration.config contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="JDBDatabase" />
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="JDBDatabase" connectionString="TestBookDB; server=Mononobe1423; Integrated Security=true;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Problem I have is when I run my code, I get the error message

**Configuration file dataConfiguration.config does not have root  tag**

As you can see above, all three files contain the configuration tag. So I am lost as to what the error is and why I am unable to access the section objects defined in the other files using either of

```
var execonfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var db = execonfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["JDBDatabase"];
```

or

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
var db =  configSource.GetSection(DatabaseSettings.SectionName);
```

Anyone know what I have wrong?

Comment: Does your exception handling config load properly?

Comment: Not certain as it currently errors out when I go to load the dataconfiguration information.

Comment: @Kobojunkie if you got the solution, please post here as I am getting the same issue.